# For loop isn't printing correct "."

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, printstream

What I am trying to do is have it take a java file that look like this

```
public class test1 {
public static void main ( string[] args ) {
System.out.println( "This is Test 1." );
}
}
```

And it is suppose to output a text file with the proper spacing and indents.
So far I can get the correct indenting for the first the lines. But I am having trouble with my second for loop that prints the spaces for the ending brackets. The ending brackets are prints outward like the first 3 lines instead of inward. Sorry if my variables are confusing.

Here is my code so far

```
public class JavaJustifier {
public static void main( String[] args ) 
           throws FileNotFoundException {

    for( int i = 1; i < 6; i++ ) {
        justifyJava( "Test" + i + ".java", 
                     "Justified" + i + ".txt", 
                     4 );
    }                
}
public static void justifyJava( String inputFileName,
                                String outputFileName,
                                int tabSize ) 
        throws FileNotFoundException {


    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int blah = 0;
    File f = new File(inputFileName);
    File p = new File(outputFileName);
    if  (p.exists())
        p.delete();
    Scanner input = new Scanner (f);
    PrintStream name = new PrintStream(new File(outputFileName));

    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
        if (line.contains("{") == true) {
            name.print("{\r\n");
            counter++;
            for (int i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= tabSize; j++) {
                    name.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println(counter);
        } else if (line.contains("}") == true) {
            name.print("\r\n");
            counter--;
            for (int x = 1; x <= counter; x++) {
                for (int y = 1; y <= tabSize; y++) {
                    name.print(" ");
                }
            }
            name.print("}");
            System.out.println(counter);
        } else {
            name.print(line);
        }
    }
}
```

What it gives me is

```
public class Test1 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) 
    {
        System.out.println( "This is Test 1." );
}
    }
```

What I desire is this

```
public class Test1 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) 
    {
        System.out.println( "This is Test 1." );
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to print and how it is currently printing with examples?

Comment: Don't write `if (line.contains("{") == true) {`, simply write `if (line.contains("{")) {`

Comment: We need to see your input file, current output, and desired output.

Comment: Remember to do some extra checks for curly braces inside string literals - otherwise your formatting will become ugly.

Comment: I don't know how you get that output because by saying `if (line.contains("{") == true) {` you are basically ignoring the rest of the text and only handling the `{`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've refactored a few things (and it was necessary) but it works exactly as you expect it to (AFAIK!).

Here's the code:

```
public class JavaJustifier {
    static int counter = 0;
    static int tabSize = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        justifyJava("Test1.java", "Justified1.txt");
    }

    private static void processLine(PrintStream name, String line) {
        if (line.contains("{")) {
            String preText = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("{"));
            String postText = line.substring(line.indexOf("{") + 1)
                    .replaceAll("\\n", "").replaceAll("\\r\\n", "");
            printSpaces(name);
            name.println(preText);
            printSpaces(name);
            name.println("{");
            counter++;
            processLine(name, postText);

        } else if (line.contains("}")) {
            String preText = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("}"));
            String postText = line.substring(line.indexOf("}") + 1)
                    .replaceAll("\\n", "").replaceAll("\\r\\n", "");
            name.println(preText);
            counter--;
            printSpaces(name);
            name.println("}");
            processLine(name, postText);
        } else {
            if (!line.equals("\r\n") && line.length() != 0) {
                printSpaces(name);
                name.print(line);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printSpaces(PrintStream p) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= tabSize; j++) {
                p.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void justifyJava(String inputFileName, String outputFileName)
            throws FileNotFoundException {

        File f = new File(inputFileName);
        File p = new File(outputFileName);
        if (p.exists())
            p.delete();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
        PrintStream name = new PrintStream(new File(outputFileName));

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine().trim();
            processLine(name, line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem with this is its great, but I can not change any of my main method, and the only code I can add is after the throws FileNotFoundException.

Comment: @BrentColeman It would be silly not to change the code or design when we know it is wrong. You need to remember the changes to `counter` and the only way I can think of in your current setup is to make it a static variable. Anything else we try and we'd be further deviating from your template. 

Change the design -- if you have to -- to get things done the right way!!